# RESTful WCF call is blocked until previous call is complete

Tags: wcf, rest

I've got a simple WCF RESTful service being hosted in IIS. I call the WCF using a browser. I call the service simultaneously using different tabs in the browser. Below is the code for the service

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWCFService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "DoWork", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string DoWork();
}

public class WCFService : IWCFService
{
    public string DoWork()
    {
        string ret = "Enter time is " + System.DateTime.Now + " " + System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        ret += ". Exiting time is " + System.DateTime.Now + " " + System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

And below is the web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFService.WCFServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFService.WCFServiceBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFService.WCFServiceBehavior" name="WCFService.WCFService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.IWCFService" behaviorConfiguration="WCFService.WCFServiceBehavior">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Even though I enter the address in quick successions the end time of the first is the beginning time of the second eg output of one page is

- Enter time is 12/05/2015 4:55:24 PM 568.
- Exiting time is 12/05/2015 4:55:34 PM 569.

then the next page is

- Enter time is 12/05/2015 4:55:34 PM 578.
- Exiting time is 12/05/2015 4:55:44 PM 579.

What is could be causing this and how do can I fix it so all calls are processed as soon as they arrive?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but you can try to set ConcurrencyMode on multiple with the ServiceBehavior attribute on the implementing class

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class WCFService : IWCFService
```

Comment: Why are you setting `InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single`? - there is nothing in the OPs requirement which needs to restrict servicing to a single instance.

Comment: I've tried adding both [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)] and [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)] and neither worked.